# Retrieve source code from an external website (e.g. google.com ) using JavaScript (or jQuery) for a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Google Chrome extension and I need the `HTML` source code from an external website, for example `google.com`. Is this possible in any way?

Comment: What do you mean, "HTML Source code"? HTML is usually not source code.

Comment: I think you know what I meant

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method to fire an asynchronous request to the web page in question. The response should be the source of that page. However, you need to add the site in question into your `manifest.json` file, in the permissions section, to allow cross-domain AJAX calls to function.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("http://www.jamesallardice.com/", function(data) {
        $("#someElem").text(data);
    });
});
```

And in the manifest file:

```
{
    "permissions": [
        "http://www.jamesallardice.com/"
    ]
}
```

See the docs on [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html) for more information.

Comment: Chrome packaged apps are allowed to do cross domain ajax just fine. I'm not sure how his extension is packaged (or hosted), but I have a package app myself which use ajax to retrieve data from any website just fine.